# connection problem using mssql with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**NoMethodError: undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #
Did you mean?  alias_method**

this error occurs when making new app in rails with sql server....
how this issue can be resolved ?

Comment: Does this method occur when you're trying to start the application or on creation? Can we see the command that triggers it please?

Comment: when i creating the database or trying to run the server then it occurs    commands: rails s and rails or rake db create or migrate

Comment: you might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442564/how-do-i-fix-in-ruby-on-rails-the-undefined-method-alias-method-chain-error

Comment: but in that they are using the postgresql here i am using MSSQL Server, i only have this problem using MSSQL Server

Comment: in my app i must have to use MSSQL Server

Comment: Which rails version you use? Which gem do you use for connecting to MSSQL? I found https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/636

Comment: gem 'activerecord'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', ruby '2.6.3',  gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'  these versions i am using  and also freetds too

Comment: @khurramrashid try to downgrade rail to 5th version